# ListPlot give special labels position with Callout

Tags: labeling

When I use ListPlot, I want to show the labels, such as

```
ListPlot[Callout[#, #, Above] & /@ Range[10], Joined -> True, Mesh -> All]
```

Now all positions are **Above**, but sometimes the labels will over other text, so I want to set some of them **Below**, for example, the second and third point labels are **Below**, as the image shows.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ListPlot[Callout[#, #, # /. {2 | 3 | 8 -> Below, _ -> Above}] & /@ Range[10], 
  Joined -> True, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way is use `MapAt`

```
data = Range[10];
mapBelow[n_] := MapAt[Callout[#, #, Below] &, n];
mapAbove[n_] := MapAt[Callout[#, #, Above] &, n];
below = Table[mapBelow[n], {n, {2, 3, 8}}];
above = Table[mapAbove[n], {n, Complement[Range[10], {2, 3, 8}]}];
ListPlot[Composition[Sequence @@ Flatten[{above, below}]][data], 
 Joined -> True, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]